# Angular get wrong path of firebase-messaging-sw.js on production

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

I'm using Firebase to get message from backend. It works perfectly on my localhost. But in production, my web served at .../XXXX and firebase-messaging-sw.js located at .../XXXX/firebase-messaging-sw.js but Angular always load .../firebase-messaging-sw.js. So, I got a 404 error. I put firebase-messaging-sw.js at src folder. Can someone explain why?
Thanks.

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
    "src/manifest.json"
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am stuck with the same problem.